# How can you filter out related words in large list quickly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I am running this code on [~479k words](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) and it is taking a very long time:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const words = fs.readFileSync('dicts/eng.csv', 'utf-8')
  .split(/\n/)
  .filter(x => x && !x.match('-') && !x.match(/[A-Z]/))
  .reduce((m, x) => {
    m[x] = true
    return m
  }, {})

for (let word in words) {
  for (let form in words) {
    if (form.indexOf(word) == 0) {
      if (form.length == word.length + 2 && form.endsWith('ed')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 4 && form.endsWith('tion')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 3 && form.endsWith('ing')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 2 && form.endsWith('er')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 2 && form.endsWith('or')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 3 && form.endsWith('est')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 1 && form.endsWith('s')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 3 && form.endsWith('ers')) {
        delete words[form]
      } else if (form.length == word.length + 4 && form.endsWith('ings')) {
        delete words[form]
      }
    }
  }
}

fs.writeFileSync('dicts/eng.out.csv', Object.keys(words).sort().join('\n'))
```

How can I speed this up to take only a fraction of the time, on the order of a second or two or whatever is more realistic?

Is there some data structure I need to convert this list into that is better suited to a faster algorithm?

Comment: That's a case for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: That said, this isn't a [mcve]. What's the content of `words`? Do you expect us all to grab the file our self and modify your example so we can actually work with it?

Comment: @Andreas yes please, the file is right there in the GitHub repo. It's too large to paste.

Comment: Then grab some sample elements and create a "fake" `words` variable with it -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: I think your else if chain misses the "f -> es" case (eg. wolf -> wolves) and some other edge case (eg. die -> dying, abbreviate -> abbreviating). I think your problem isn't just a coding one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let words = fs.readFileSync('dicts/eng.csv', 'utf-8')
  .split(/\n/)
  .filter(x => x && !x.match('-') && !x.match(/[A-Z]/)).sort()

let out = new Set, root = words[0];
for (let word of words) {
    if (!word.startsWith(root))
        root = word;
    word = root === word ? root : word
        .replace(/(ed|tion|ing|er|or|est|s|ers|ings)$/, '')
    out.add(word);
}

fs.writeFileSync('dicts/eng.out.csv', [...out].join('\n'));
```